# Evaluate JSon with null value using Freemarker

Tags: json, jackson, freemarker

When dealing with a JSon that some values are null Freemarker give an error in ?eval.

with `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL)` i can avoid this but i miss this information on the generated JSon.

There's a way to achieve the evaluation with this null values?

```
<#assign test = "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}">
<#assign m = test?eval>
${m.foo}  <#-- prints: bar -->
```

Fail in eval

```
<#assign test = "{\"foo\":null}">
<#assign m = test?eval> <#-- fail in eval -->
${m.foo}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** FreeMarker 2.3.31 added `?eval_json`. It can parse `null`, and can't call methods (which is a possible security issue with `?eval`).

Unfortunately (or... infuriatingly), FTL doesn't know the concept of `null` (although this might will change with 2.4). So even if you manage to create a `Map` from that JSON where the `foo` key exists but the associated value is `null` (like you create a such `Map` in Java), `${m.foo}` will still fail. Surely you can write `${m.foo!'null'}`, but that will print `null` even if there's no `foo` key at all. So maybe it's better if you provide a default value for the `null`-s *during the JSON evaluation*:

```
<#function parseJSON json>
  <#local null = 'null'> <#-- null is not a keyword in FTL -->
  <#return json?eval>
</#function>

${parseJSON("{\"foo\":null}").foo}  <#-- prints null -->
```

Now, however, you can't tell the difference between `"null"` and `null`. If that's a problem, you could chose some odd default, like `'@@@null'` or even use a macro as indicator value and then use `?is_macro` to test if the value was `null` (that hack is useful as JSON evaluation can't produce macros)...